# Docusign Retrieve via ProcessBuilder

Tags: c#, docusignapi, processbuilder

I'm attempting to build a java process to execute the docusign retrieve product via the command line.  I've written the process to execute based on a given property file.

```
        buildRoot = isWindowsOs() ? "C:" + "\\Program Files (x86)\\DocuSign, Inc\\Retrieve 3.2" : "\\Program Files (x86)\\DocuSign, Inc\\Retrieve 3.2" ;

        String[] command = new String [2];

        command[0] = "\""+buildRoot+ "\\" + docuSignAppName+"\"";
        logger.info(command[0].toString());
        //ADDED FOR EXPLANATION - "C:\Program Files (x86)\DocuSign, Inc\Retrieve 3.2\DocuSignRetrieve.exe"
        command[1] = arguments;
        logger.info(command[1].toString());

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        logger.info("ProcessBuilder starting directory" +processBuilder.directory());
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        p = processBuilder.start();

        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        stdout = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

Once I pass in the built out string of parameters the executed code looks like the sample provided but always results in the error back to the screen "Missing "accountid" parameter".

The parameter list looks like the following.
    /endpoint "Demo" 
    /userid "REMOVED" 
    /password "REMOVED" 
    /accountid "REMOVED" 
    /span "-1" 
    /spanfilter "Completed" 
    /statusfilter "Completed" 
    /fieldlog "LIST OF FIELDS" 
    /nstyle "EnvelopeID" 
    /save "MergedPdfWithoutCert" 
    /dir "D:\DocuSignStore" 
    /includeheaders "true"

Any help or assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you positive you are entering the correct `accountid` associated with the user you are passing in?  Also are you entering the 5 digit account id or the 32-digit API GUID as the `accountid`?

Comment: Either works, although as specified in the example command line script builder, I will likely use the 32 digit accountid and user ids.  My issue was the with the way I was coding the process builder.

Comment: You should post how you resolved for the benefit of the community and to help others who might run into the same thing...

Comment: Ergin - Thanks for the reminder.  See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was found in a StackOverflow discussion regarding common issues with the ProcessBuilder.

My problem was that I expected by changing the putting in the full path, that I could run the executable.  For the reason I'm not sure right now, that wasn't working as expected.  The solution was to run the CMD command which exists on the %PATH% on any windows OS.

```
    String[] command = new String [2];

    command[0] = "\""+buildRoot+ "\\" + docuSignAppName+"\"";
    logger.info(command[0].toString());
    //ADDED FOR EXPLANATION - "C:\Program Files (x86)\DocuSign, Inc\Retrieve 3.2\DocuSignRetrieve.exe"
    command[1] = arguments;
    logger.info(command[1].toString());
    //This starts a new command prompt
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","DocusignRetreive.exe);
    //This sets the directory to run the command prompt from
    File newLoc = new File("C:/Program Files (x86)/DocuSign, Inc/Retrieve 3.2");
    processBuilder.directory(newLoc);
    logger.info("ProcessBuilder starting directory" +processBuilder.directory());
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

    /*When the process builder starts the prompt looks like
     *C:\Program Files (x86)\DocuSign, Inc\Retrieve 3.2
     *Now DocusignRetrieve.exe is an executable in the directory to be run
     */
    p = processBuilder.start();
```